# Compressing folders with long paths

Tags: powershell

I am now the proud owner of my company's off-boarding script (Yay!).  I have been going through the code and testing, and I noticed that on some users' homefolders I am hitting PowerShell's 260 character limit.  This is a problem because our policy states that anyone on "litigation hold" that leaves the company needs to have their entire homefolder compressed and stored until legal releases it (so forever in other words).  The rest of the script runs great and takes care of EVERYTHING else so I would like this process to stay in PowerShell.

I have tried numerous ways/methods/workarounds and I havent found one that works yet.  Here is what I have tried:

**AlphaFS** : Can get all of the file names, but chokes when I send the output to a native cmdlet (Not surprising)
**AlphaFS Compress** : Not recursive
**7-Zip** : Doesn't retain timestamps properly
**ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib** : Hits PS character limit

*Edit : I also tried **QuickIO.NET** but didn't get passed the PS limit with the compress method.
*Edit2 : Tried **System.IO.Compression.FileSystem** - Hits PS character limit

I unfortunately can't post the code, but the idea is pretty simple.

**HomeFolder --> PowerShell --> CompressedFile**

I can load whatever modules I might need to in the script but its got to stay PowerShell and the folder contents need to be compressed into one file.  I am hoping this is even possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: [`New-Zipfile`, `Expand-Zipfile`](http://ss64.com/ps/zip.html) article could help?

Comment: No dice.  I have already tried System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, I guess I should have mentioned that.  Unfortunately, it is also bound by the PS limit.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this in PowerShell natively. I'd recommend writing a C# CLI program to accomplish the task, you'll still be-able to call it from PowerShell while having far easier options for bypassing the 260 character limit.

Comment: How much of the path is INSIDE the user's homefolder?  Can you change to the user's homefolder then call your archive function?  I have seen paths like `\\fullyqualifiedservername.domainname.topleveldomain\fileshares\$private\users\department\users-a-j\first.middle.last\profile\homedrive`.  I know yours isn't this bad but it wouldn't take much to push that to 260.  A simple `cd first.middle.last` followed by `Archive-Deadbeat -input *.* -output \\path\to\archive\first.middle.last.date`

Comment: Similar to the above advice, and something we sometimes do: you can map a drive letter directly into the root of their home drive (e.g. x:), then zip from there.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using emcopy / robocopy to move the directory to a shorter path length.

Then you would easily be able to manipulate it how you want in powershell.

Even if that is zipping it and then moving it back with emcopy

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an SO type answer but since you mentioned you are already using AlphaFS.. AlphaFS actually does have a recursive compression option, you just need to pass the option, as described [Here](http://alphafs.alphaleonis.com/doc/2.0/api/html/66B68363.htm) basically just need to add `,32` to your method call so something like `[Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory]::Compress($path,32)`

Keep in mind however that this uses NTFS compression rather than creating a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described it sounds like Get-ChildItem's 260 character restriction is stopping you from sending the paths to the zip program.

I work around this issue using [Get-FolderItem](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Deeply-Nested-Files-a2148fd7), which parses the output of Robocopy to get the full paths of files in a folder - thankfully Robocopy has a 65,535 character limit on paths. Get-FolderItem doesn't support recursive folder traversal, so you'll still need to use `Get-ChildItem -Directory` to recursively retrieve all of the folders.

Example:

```
    $homeDirectoryFolders = Get-ChildItem $homeDirectory -Recurse -Directory

    ForEach ($HDFolder in $homeDirectoryFolders) {
        $homeDirectoryFiles = Get-FolderItem $HDFolder.FullName
    }

    #Zip $homeDirectoryFiles here
```